# Recursive function inside IF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a piece of code that executes if a certain condition is met. In my case, if the url matches.

```
function urlRandom () {
  var urls = $('a[href*="wiki-"]');
  var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);
  var trgt = urls.get(rndm);
  // psuedocode begins
  if(trgt contains url "wiki-one" or "wiki-two") {
   do this
  }
  else {
   // recursively call urlRandom() to fetch a new random url
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to code the portion written as psuedocode.

Comment: You can't do `if (x == y or z)`, you must do `if (x == y or x == z)`.

Comment: What is `wiki-one` and `wiki-two`? You need to give us something more to work with here. Are those numbers? Strings?

Comment: Yes @tadman they are strings. Good point Eugene. "do this"in the IF block refers to a function that will be called. Won't that take care of it?

Comment: if(trgt.contains("wiki-one") || trgt.contains("wiki-two"){ dothis } is this what you want? or you want the do this part?

Comment: This all seems like a needlessly complex way to find a url that matches "wiki-one" or "wiki-two". Why do you need it to be recursive? Can't you just have ```$('a[href*="wiki-one"]').get(0) || $('a[href*="wiki-two"]').get(0)```. Can you elaborate on the exact reasoning why you need it to be recursive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this to make your function return a random `href` and search again if the `href` is either "wiki-one" or "wiki-two":

```
function urlRandom() {
  var urls = $('a[href*="wiki-"]');
  var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length);
  var trgt = urls.get(rndm).attr('href');

  if (["wiki-one","wiki-two"].indexOf(trgt) === -1) {
    return trgt;
  }
  return urlRandom();
}
```

You can make the last bit even shorter by using a ternary operator but I used the `if` to explicitly define the code paths:

```
return ["wiki-one","wiki-two"].indexOf(trgt) === -1 ? trgt : urlRandom();
```

Comment: this looks great. instead of return trgt I want to call writeDB(). Is that ok or do I have to call writeDB() as well as return trgt.

Comment: So basically I want to do
return ["wiki-one","wiki-two"].indexOf(trgt) === -1 ? writeDB() : urlRandom();

Comment: You can do anything you want at that line, make sure you return out of the function because otherwise you will end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can create the recursive logic, however this assumes that in some iteration you will find `wiki-one` or `wiki-two` .Otherwise the program will not end.

I have left the else part logic how will construct the url arrays.

```
function urlRandom (urls) {
  if(!urls) {
   urls = $('a[href*="wiki-"]');
  }
  var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);
  var trgt = urls.get(rndm);
  // psuedocode begins
  if(trgt.indexOf("wiki-one") !== -1 || trgt.indexOf("wiki-two") !== -1) {
    //do this
    return something;
  }
  else {
    urls = <build here new url collection with whatever logic you want>
    return urlRandom(urls);
}
```

You can call this

```
urlRandom();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using link elements and href attributes, you can translate the logic into your code easily.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/omw9uqer/7/

Code

```
  var urls = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  console.log(urls);

  function urlRandom(urls) {
    if (urls.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length);
    var trgt = urls[rndm].href;
    if (trgt.indexOf('moveright1') > -1 || trgt.indexOf('moveright2') > -1) {
      console.log('element found!!', trgt);
      return;
    } else {
      urlRandom(urls);
    }
  }



urlRandom(urls);
```

Comment: What do you think `urlRandom(urls);` will do at line 11?

Comment: Nevermind. I assumed you wanted to return something because of the return statements but it's actually just exiting out of the function. Props for not using jQuery.